# Codeigniter 3 pagination class with bootstrap 4

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter, pagination

Is Codeigniter 3 compatible with Bootstrap 4? or is it simply way too outdated to add any uses for bootstrap 4?

I've been looking at tutorials online on how to integrate bootstrap to Codeigniter pagination.

So far all i've seen is that they mostly changed the $config of the pagination class. For example:

```
//config for bootstrap pagination class integration
$config['full_tag_open'] = '<ul class="pagination">';
$config['full_tag_close'] = '</ul>';
$config['first_link'] = false;
$config['last_link'] = false;
$config['first_tag_open'] = '<li>';
$config['first_tag_close'] = '</li>';
$config['prev_link'] = '&laquo';
$config['prev_tag_open'] = '<li class="prev">';
$config['prev_tag_close'] = '</li>';
$config['next_link'] = '&raquo';
$config['next_tag_open'] = '<li>';
$config['next_tag_close'] = '</li>';
$config['last_tag_open'] = '<li>';
$config['last_tag_close'] = '</li>';
$config['cur_tag_open'] = '<li class="active"><a href="#">';
$config['cur_tag_close'] = '</a></li>';
$config['num_tag_open'] = '<li>';
$config['num_tag_close'] = '</li>';
```

I wanted a clear divide in my codes. Simply, I wanted less PHP in my HTML and more HTML there.

This is the Pagination code snippet in w3school bootstrap 4 tutorial.

```
<ul class="pagination">
  <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">Previous</a></li>
  <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">1</a></li>
  <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">2</a></li>
  <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">3</a></li>
  <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">Next</a></li>
</ul>
```

How do I integrate the above code to my pagination class?

Do I have to do it the way the above tutorial did? or can I simply use a `foreach` loop in my HTML/view page to create the links depending on the records from the database?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code you added belongs to Bootstrap-3. Try this

```
$config['full_tag_open'] = '<ul class="pagination">';
$config['full_tag_close'] = '</ul>';
$config['first_link'] = false;
$config['last_link'] = false;
$config['first_tag_open'] = '<li class="page-item">';
$config['first_tag_close'] = '</li>';
$config['prev_link'] = '&laquo';
$config['prev_tag_open'] = '<li class="page-item prev">';
$config['prev_tag_close'] = '</li>';
$config['next_link'] = '&raquo';
$config['next_tag_open'] = '<liclass="page-item">';
$config['next_tag_close'] = '</li>';
$config['last_tag_open'] = '<liclass="page-item">';
$config['last_tag_close'] = '</li>';
$config['cur_tag_open'] = '<li class="page-item active"><a class="page-link">';
$config['cur_tag_close'] = '</a></li>';
$config['num_tag_open'] = '<li class="page-item">';
$config['num_tag_close'] = '</li>';
```

Comment: There really is no way to do this in HTML right? 

I tried to do it but it went against my needs as i wanted to do less PHP in my html but coding this mainly in HTML made me code more php in my view.

Comment: Btw, why can't i get the first and last link to appear?

  $config['first_link'] = 'First';
  $config['last_link'] = 'Last';

I even changed the per page to 2 to make it print more than 3 links.

Answer (score 16):

The best. You have tried many, but this one is the one that best fit the page.

```
// Bootstrap 4, work very fine.
$config['full_tag_open'] = '<ul class="pagination">';
$config['full_tag_close'] = '</ul>';
$config['attributes'] = ['class' => 'page-link'];
$config['first_link'] = false;
$config['last_link'] = false;
$config['first_tag_open'] = '<li class="page-item">';
$config['first_tag_close'] = '</li>';
$config['prev_link'] = '&laquo';
$config['prev_tag_open'] = '<li class="page-item">';
$config['prev_tag_close'] = '</li>';
$config['next_link'] = '&raquo';
$config['next_tag_open'] = '<li class="page-item">';
$config['next_tag_close'] = '</li>';
$config['last_tag_open'] = '<li class="page-item">';
$config['last_tag_close'] = '</li>';
$config['cur_tag_open'] = '<li class="page-item active"><a href="#" class="page-link">';
$config['cur_tag_close'] = '<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>';
$config['num_tag_open'] = '<li class="page-item">';
$config['num_tag_close'] = '</li>';
```

Comment: Thank you, this is awesome. Works for mee too.

Comment: Worked for me when I added: `$config['attributes'] = ['class' => 'page-link'];`

Answer (score 2):

This works for me

```
    // Bootstrap 4 Pagination fix
    $config['full_tag_open']    = '<div class="pagging text-center"><nav><ul class="pagination">';
    $config['full_tag_close']   = '</ul></nav></div>';
    $config['num_tag_open']     = '<li class="page-item"><span class="page-link">';
    $config['num_tag_close']    = '</span></li>';
    $config['cur_tag_open']     = '<li class="page-item active"><span class="page-link">';
    $config['cur_tag_close']    = '<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></span></li>';
    $config['next_tag_open']    = '<li class="page-item"><span class="page-link">';
    $config['next_tag_close']  = '<span aria-hidden="true"></span></span></li>';
    // $config['next_tag_close']  = '<span aria-hidden="true">&raquo;</span></span></li>';
    $config['prev_tag_open']    = '<li class="page-item"><span class="page-link">';
    $config['prev_tag_close']  = '</span></li>';
    $config['first_tag_open']   = '<li class="page-item"><span class="page-link">';
    $config['first_tag_close'] = '</span></li>';
    $config['last_tag_open']    = '<li class="page-item"><span class="page-link">';
    $config['last_tag_close']  = '</span></li>';
```

Comment: Hi Guys, what if one need to create SEO friendly URL like www.example.com/blog?page=2

Comment: @RizwanRanjha, you can set `$config['page_query_string'] = TRUE;`

Comment: @Orion, what is that class "pagging" ?

Comment: @tatskie, you can actually omit that, that was used to test some styling on the div when I was working on it then.

Answer (score 2):

Best solution

```
$config['full_tag_open']    = '<nav aria-label="Page navigation"><ul class="pagination">';
$config['full_tag_close']   = '</ul></nav>';
$config['num_tag_open']     = '<li class="page-item">';
$config['num_tag_close']    = '</li>';
$config['cur_tag_open']     = '<li class="page-item active"><span class="page-link">';
$config['cur_tag_close']    = '</span></li>';
$config['next_tag_open']    = '<li class="page-item">';
$config['next_tag_close']  = '</li>';
$config['prev_tag_open']    = '<li class="page-item">';
$config['prev_tag_close']  = '</li>';
$config['first_tag_open']   = '<li class="page-item">';
$config['first_tag_close'] = '</li>';
$config['last_tag_open']    = '<li class="page-item">';
$config['last_tag_close']  = '</li>';
```

then Add page-link class to a tag via jquery

```
    jquery('.page-item>a').addClass("page-link");
```

Comment: Yes this worked: `$config['attributes'] = ['class' => 'page-link'];` Why to bother adding jQuery when you can add directly from HTML as suggested by @Rodrigo Prazim

Answer (score 2):

I have tried and succeeded

```
//Style for BootStrap v4
    $config['next_link']        = 'Next';
    $config['prev_link']        = 'Prev';
    $config['first_link']       = false;
    $config['last_link']        = false;
    $config['full_tag_open']    = '<ul class="pagination justify-content-center">';
    $config['full_tag_close']   = '</ul>';
    $config['attributes']       = ['class' => 'page-link'];
    $config['first_tag_open']   = '<li class="page-item">';
    $config['first_tag_close']  = '</li>';
    $config['prev_tag_open']    = '<li class="page-item">';
    $config['prev_tag_close']   = '</li>';
    $config['next_tag_open']    = '<li class="page-item">';
    $config['next_tag_close']   = '</li>';
    $config['last_tag_open']    = '<li class="page-item">';
    $config['last_tag_close']   = '</li>';
    $config['cur_tag_open']     = '<li class="page-item active"><span class="page-link">';
    $config['cur_tag_close']    = '<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></span></li>';
    $config['num_tag_open']     = '<li class="page-item">';
    $config['num_tag_close']    = '</li>';
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZBCCE.png)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it could be useful / easier to understand if you explain what you did and how the code block is relevant, instead of only pasting the code.

Comment: You are savior bro. I tried many solutions none of them was able to add this page-link class inside <a> tag but you did it. Thanks a lot