# Codeigniter 3 pagination class and Query String with bootstrap 4

Tags: php, codeigniter, bootstrap-4

I am trying to use Bootstrap 4 with Codeigniter Pagination but want to add ?page=number. I am able to create pagination and it is working fine without

> ?page=number

but I need to use this for making it more SEO Friendly. I am already using this example but unable to get it working with Query String. Here is my code to enable Query String with the below example;

```
$config['enable_query_strings'] = TRUE;
$config['page_query_string'] = TRUE;
$config['use_page_numbers'] = TRUE;
$config['query_string_segment'] = 'page';
```

1. [Codeigniter 3 pagination class with bootstrap 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47846071/codeigniter-3-pagination-class-with-bootstrap-4)

I will be really thankful, if someone can help me or guide me on this. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

make sure you give valid URL in base-url config, you can remove all the params from URL like this.

```
$url = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
$config['base_url'] = site_url($url['path']);
```

and add

```
$config['reuse_query_string'] = true;
```

Comment: Hi Sir, when  do not enable Query String, It is working fine unable to unable to get the point that why we have to again add base_url.

Comment: Your problem has nothing to do with the config file. What I think is happening is that your results are not correct.

When you use uri segments for the pagination all you have to do is send that number into your query and use that directly has offset. However, when you use page number that will not be the same as your offset. That way you'll have to do something like (Page_number x YourOffset)